# I don't understand what they mean when runtime will decide which overriden method gets called

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual-functions

polymorphism example:

```
public class animal 
{
    public void virtual speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animals can speak in many ways.");
    }
}

public class dog : animal 
{
    public void override speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I bark!");
    }
}

static void main()
{
    animal doggy = new dog();

    doggy.speak();
}
```

output:

```
I bark!
```

I keep reading that the correct speak method is called during runtime, but is it not already hard coded and does the compiler not recognize which method it will invoke based on the virtual and override keywords?

Comment: This is a polymorphism question and technically applies to any OO supported language (Java/C++/VB.net, etc. etc.). The answers below are correct, but just wanted to clarify the compiler 'hard codes' (assembles) the types into the binary, the 'runtime' (i.e. the assembled running code/exe) decides which 'type' is returned based on the compiled decision tree.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler doesn't necessarily know which implementation will be the underlying type. Take, for example:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}

class Program
{
    static A GetImpl(int i)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                return new A();
            case 2:
                return new B();
            default:
                // whatever
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        A a = GetImpl(i);
        a.F();
    }
}
```

How could the compiler possibly know if an `A` or a `B` is returned?  It cannot, so the task of calling the correct method is delegated to the runtime.

Comment: I understand what you are saying clearly, but some books use the hard coded example that I provided and tell me that the runtime will decide which method is called. that's what confused me. thanks.

Comment: @JoeDugan: Well, they may be technically correct, but I think an example like this makes it more obvious as to *why* things are the way they are.

Answer (score 1):

If your code was something like

```
Animal anAnimal= NoahsArc.getNextAnimal();
anAnimal.speak();
```

Now you don't actually know what sort of animal you are going to get, so the runtime ensures the correct `speak` method is called.